# Not able to append the return of a function when I read csv files using a for loop.

Tags: r

The issue i am facing is I am getting individual lists for each .csv i read and it is not appending the result to a single dataframe or list. I am very new to R. Please help me out.
I am getting output as 
amazon.csv 10.07
facebook.csv 54.67

Whereas i am expecting all the values in a data frame with column company and CAGR values.

```
enter code here

preprocess <- function(x){


  ##flipping data to suit time series analysis
  my.data <- x[nrow(x):1,]

  #sort(x,)

  ## setting up date as date format
  my.data$date <- as.Date(my.data$date)

  ##creating a new data frame to sort the data.
  sorted.data <- my.data[order(my.data$date),]

  #removing the last row as it contains stocks price at moment when i downloaded data
  #sorted.data <- sorted.data[-nrow(sorted.data),]
  #calculating lenght of the data frame
  data.length <- length(sorted.data$date)

  ## extracting the first date
  time.min <- sorted.data$date[1]
  ##extracting the last date
  time.max <- sorted.data$date[data.length]

  # creating a new data frame with all the dates in sequence
  all.dates <- seq(time.min, time.max, by="day")
  all.dates.frame <- data.frame(list(date=all.dates))

  #Merging all dates data frame and sorted data frame; all the empty cells are assigned NA vales
  merged.data <- merge(all.dates.frame, sorted.data, all=T)

  ##Replacing all NA values with the values of the rows of previous day
  final.data <- transform(merged.data, close = na.locf(close), open = na.locf(open), volume = na.locf(volume), high = na.locf(high), low =na.locf(low))
 # write.csv(final.data, file = "C:/Users/rites/Downloads/stock prices", row.names = FALSE)

#
 #return(final.data) #--> ##{remove comment for Code Check}







  ################################################################
  ######calculation of  CAGR(Compound Annual Growth Rate ) #######
  #### {((latest price/Oldest price)^1/#ofyears) - 1}*100 ########
  ################################################################

  ##Extracting closing price of the oldest date


 old_closing_price <- final.data$close[1]

  ##extracting the closing price of the latest date
 new_closing_price <- final.data$close[length(final.data$close)]

  ##extracting the starting year
 start_date <- final.data$date[1]
  start_year <- as.numeric(format(start_date, "%Y"))

  ##extracting the latest date
  end_date <- final.data$date[length(final.data$date)]
 end_year <- as.numeric(format(end_date, "%Y"))

  CAGR_1 <- new_closing_price/old_closing_price
  root <- 1/(end_year-start_year)

 CAGR <- (((CAGR_1)^(root))-1)*100
  return (CAGR)

}

temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp))
  assign(temp[i], preprocess (read.csv(temp[i])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create an empty data frame and append to this in the loop. You're using assign at the moment which creates variables, not in a data frame. try something like:

```
df<-data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(temp)){


   preproc <- preprocess(read.csv(temp[i]))) 

   df<-rbind(df,data.frame(company = paste0(temp[i]),
                           value = preproc))

}
```